# Android can't send "id" to this php

Tags: android, mysql

I am doing an android-php-mysql connection. I have tried this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

request.setURI(new URI("http://iamjavadeveloper.com/NoTitle.php"));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request); 

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

and the php file is:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from titles");

while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
        $output[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

But this doesn't work;

the php:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from titles where id='$id' " );

while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
        $output[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

and the java:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

request.setURI(new URI("http://iamjavadeveloper.com/NoTitle.php?id=23"));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

and the Logcat:

```
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758): Process: com.example.onur, PID: 2758
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at com.example.onur.MainActivity$MarkOnMap.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:415)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at com.example.onur.MainActivity$MarkOnMap.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-20 00:50:41.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2758):         ... 4 more
```

Comment: Sorry. Kodlarda bir sıkıntı yok. Ben php'yi başka bir yerde daha çağırmışım. Bu da iki gündür gözümden kaçmış. E öyle gramerlı mıramırlı ingilizce de olmadığı için direkt türkçe yazdım. Şimdi siz düşünün.

Answer (score 0):

Please post detailed code. As per stacktrace,looks like you are trying to access UI thread from doInBackground().

make sure that you are not accessing any UI code i.e Toast in doInBackGround() method.

Comment: All the codes are same. I only add "?id=23" to end of the url and only change php from "select * from titles" to "select * from titles where id='$id'". The first codes run and return 3 results. But the changed codes don't run. But when i run on browser "iamjavadeveloper.com/?id=23", it runs and returns results. :(

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

**MainActivity.class**

```
 new ParserClass(new CalbackListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).execute();
```

**your Parser class**

```
package com.example.soapsample;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class ParserClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

public interface CalbackListener {
    public void onSuccess(String result);
}

private CalbackListener callback;
private String url = "http://iamjavadeveloper.com/NoTitle.php?id=23";

public ParserClass(CalbackListener callback1) {
    this.callback = callback1;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.i("url", url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        if (httpGet != null) {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.i("Result", result);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    callback.onSuccess(result);
}
}
```

it will return some values, ensure your url and return values.